# Hamburger menu is not correctly placed in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

[image: please find the attached picture]

Hi everyone i am working on hamburger menu in android application, where my problem is the hamburger menu is placed at wrong place(few steps down). I need the hamburger menu below my tool bar of window. please help me in this regard.
My java code:

```
// Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
// Creating Hamburger Menu
final TextView userName_ham = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.userName_hamburger);
ParseQuery<DriverDetails> query = new ParseQuery<DriverDetails>("driverDetails");    
Log.d(TAG_NAME, "Driver Phone No" + driverPhoneNo); 
query.whereEqualTo("PhoneNo", driverPhoneNo);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<DriverDetails>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<DriverDetails> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            if (objects.size() != 0) {
                driverName = objects.get(0).getString("driverNameFirst");
                Log.d(TAG_NAME, "DriverName inside" + driverName);
                editor.putString("driverName", driverName);
                editor.apply();
                userName_ham.setText("Welcome " + driverName);
            }
        }
        }
    });
Log.d(TAG_NAME, "DriverName" + driverName);
mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Earnings", R.drawable.earnings));
mNavItems.add(new NavItem("History", R.drawable.history)); 
mNavItems.add(new NavItem("About", R.drawable.about));
mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Share", R.drawable.share));
mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Notification", R.drawable.notification));
mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Settings", R.drawable.settings));
mNavItems.add(new NavItem("Logout", R.drawable.logout));
// DrawerLayout
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
// Populate the Navigation Drawer with options
mDrawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerPane); 
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
DrawerListAdapter drawerAdapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
mDrawerList.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
// Drawer Item click listeners
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItemFromDrawer(position);
    }
});
```

My xml file code:

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_gravity="start">

<!-- Profile Box -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/profileBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName_hamburger"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="View Profile"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.DriverScreenActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
<include layout="@layout/content_customer_screen" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160sp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_logout" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post activity xml also

Comment: Hi Jayanth, I have posted activity xml file also in new update. please check it.

Comment: i cant see any drawerLayout on your xml.

Comment: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout